# Where is Rapportive's "Claim your email address" option in new Gmail interface?

Tags: gmail, user-interface, rapportive

I am using Rapportive with my official email address. I need add my personal email address to same profile.

I have found that there is option for the same. It's "[Claim your email addresses!](http://blog.rapportive.com/claim-your-email-addresses)" feature. But it's broken with new Gmail interface.

So, where can I find "Claim your email addresses" feature?